# как в node js сделать curl или file get content

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

как в node js сделать curl или file get content использую фреймворк express
что б выполнить запрос к api яндекс диска

```html
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

```html
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

Comment: Классика:  https://github.com/request/request

Comment: @diproart сделал как в примере но не срабатывает страница просто грузится

Comment: Нужен пример кода, чтобы понимать, что вы делаете. Скорее всего неправильные настройки запроса или сам URL.

Comment: @diproart в вопрос внес код

Comment: результат тут http://a0197766.xsph.ru/

Comment: ссылка "результат" не работает. проверил первый и второй примеры, всё работает так как надо.

Comment: @diproart  может еще нужно http сервер создать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**!не проверял**

## package/axios

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
https://github.com/axios/axios

axios - аналог fetch

> https://disjoint.ca/til/2017/09/20/how-to-download-a-binary-file-using-axios/
>
> ```
>    import axios from 'axios';
>    import fs from 'fs';
>    
>    // ...
>    
>    return axios.request({
>      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
>      url: 'http://www.example.com/file.mp3',
>      method: 'get',
>      headers: {
>        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
>      },
>    }).then((result) => {
>      const outputFilename = '/tmp/file.mp3';
>      fs.writeFileSync(outputFilename,result.data);
>      return outputFilename;
>    });
> ```

---

### package/curl

https://www.npmjs.com/package/curl

Functions

```
curl.get(url, options, function(err, response, body) {});
curl.post(url, body, options, function(err, response, body) {});
curl.getJSON(url, options, function(err, response, data){});
curl.postJSON(url, data, options, function(err, response, data){});
```

Answer (score 0):

вот пример работы с API Яндекс Диск

https://github.com/Kolyaj/yandex-disk это может быть точкой старта для дальнейшего анализа и разработки собственного решения.

Сам по себе node/expess - это уже http-server и можно отправлять запросы [используя API Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) или использовать библиотеки/модули

- [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [request](https://github.com/request/request)
- и другие [например](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html)